# How to constrain the camera to look at an object in python script

Tags: python, scripting, objects, camera, constraints

The function i have created thus far:

```
def CameraLock(self):
    bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="Camera")
    bpy.ops.object.constraint_add(type='TRACK_TO')
    #c = bpy.data.objects["Camera"].constraints["Track to"]
    #c.target = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
    #c.track_axis = "-Z"
```

The code firstly selects the camera to be the active object which allows me to add a constraint.However when i uncomment the next two lines to track the cube the code fails and blender closes.

i have been trying to read up other ways of adding the constraint but thus far have failed to find another solution.